# Concatenate distinct values from multiple rows and multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this table:

```
VAT | Email1 | Email2
000 | a@a.it | b@b.it
000 | a@a.it | -
000 | a@a.it | c@c.it
000 |  -      | d@d.it
```

I want this result:

```
VAT | Emails
000 |  a@a.it, b@b.it, c@c.it, d@d.it
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Note that I want to concatenate values from multiple columns **and** multiple rows simultaneously.

Comment: Select distinct t2.email1, 
               substring((Select ', '+t1.email2
                From #temp1 t1
                Where T1.email1= T2.email1
                ORDER BY T1.email1
                For XML PATH ('')),2, 1000) email
         From #temp1 T2

Comment: @DanielMarcus this is not what I want to obtain.

Comment: Perhaps have to do subquery concatenation for each field then concatenate those results.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's not an exact duplicate of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv) Lad2025 linked to, 
but the answers to that question does show how to convert values of different rows into a comma separated string.
The one thing you have left to do is to get a distinct list of emails per vat from both columns.
Here is one way to do it:

First, Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    VAT char(3),
    Email1 char(6),
    Email2 char(6)
)

INSERT INTO @T(VAT,Email1, Email2) VALUES
('000', 'a@a.it', 'b@b.it'),
('000', 'a@a.it', NULL),
('000', 'a@a.it', 'c@c.it'),
('000', NULL, 'd@d.it')
```

Then, use a common table expression to combine values from `email1` and `email2` using `union`.
Note that `union` will remove duplicate values so you will get a distinct list of emails for each vat value:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT VAT, Email1 As Email
    FROM @T
    UNION
    SELECT VAT, Email2
    FROM @T
)
```

Then use `for xml path` to get a comma delimited list from the email column of the cte (that will ignore the `null` values), and `stuff` to remove the first comma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VAT, 
                (
                    SELECT STUFF(
                        (SELECT ',' + Email
                        FROM CTE t1
                        WHERE t0.VAT = t1.VAT
                        FOR XML PATH(''))
                        , 1, 1, '')
                ) As Emails
FROM CTE t0
```

Results:

```
VAT     Emails
000     a@a.it,b@b.it,c@c.it,d@d.it
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, but the above might be faster.

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE(VAT varchar(10), Email1 varchar(50), Email2 varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @TBL select '000','a@a.it','b@b.it'
INSERT INTO @TBL  select '000','a@a.it',''
INSERT INTO @TBL  select '000','a@a.it','c@c.it'
INSERT INTO @TBL select '000','pizz@pizza.com','d@d.it'
INSERT INTO @TBL select '001','slice@pizza.com','d@d.it'
INSERT INTO @TBL select '001','pizz@pizza.com','q@q.it'
INSERT INTO @TBL select '001','cheese@pizza.com','s@s.it'
INSERT INTO @TBL select '001','slice@pizza.com','s@s.it'
INSERT INTO @TBL select '001',NULL,'s@s.it'

SELECT VAT, '' + REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(( select x.Email + ','
FROM (
    select VAT, Email1 as Email 
    from @TBL T2 
    WHERE T2.VAT = T1.VAT
        AND ISNULL(Email1,'') > ''
    GROUP BY VAT, EMAIL1
    union 
    select VAT, Email2 as Email 
    from @TBL T3 
    WHERE T3.VAT = T1.VAT
        AND ISNULL(Email2,'') > ''
    GROUP BY VAT, EMAIL2
) x
FOR XML PATH('')
)), 1, 1, '' ) ) + '' as Email
from @TBL T1
GROUP by T1.VAT
```

Results:

```
VAT | Email
000 | a@a.it,b@b.it,c@c.it,d@d.it,pizz@pizza.com
001 | cheese@pizza.com,d@d.it,pizz@pizza.com,q@q.it,s@s.it,slice@pizza.com
```